# Sum of Numeric values in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, scripting

I'm new to Perl scripting and now working on a program to improve my knowledge in Perl. For example I have a input file which has data in pattern date, transaction ID, name of website, amount, I'm trying here to get sum of all transactions that are made in www.example.com. Since there are two numeric fields (transaction ID & amount) I'm unable to pick only single value (either amount or transaction ID) using the below command

```
$var =~ m/(\d+)/
```

Here is the sample input file.

```
26/06/2018 12890765 www.example.com 986.00
31/08/2018 17464946 www.other.com 7627.00
1/05/2018  65472345 www.example.com 14.00
```

Now help me how can I pick only 986 or 7627 or 14 from the file and 
So here if run a code with www.example.com as argument I should get sum as 1000.

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. What did you try to solve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

Split each line on whitespace, examine the last two elements - if the second one from right is the same as the first argument of the program, add the last one to the sum.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $domain = shift;

my $sum = 0;
while (<>) {
    my @cells = split;
    $sum += $cells[-1] if $cells[-2] eq $domain;
}
print "$sum\n";
```

Call as

```
script.pl www.example.com file.txt
```

Comment: Pedantically, `www.example.com` is a domain, not a URL :-)

Comment: Thanks, fixed. Was under the influence of ran_0315's reply :)

Answer (score 1):

Use look behind `(?<=www\.example\.com )(\d+\.\d+)` This will match the digit next to the domain you give inside the `(?<= )`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/smvXz6/2)

Comment: There's no URL in this code. There's a domain, but no URL :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
$var =~ m/.+?www.example.com.+?(\d+\.\d{2})$/m
```

This should match against number values at the end of the string / line, where the substring "www.example.com" appears previously in the string / line.

The value you are interested in will be in capture group 1 (in perl I believe this defaults to a variable called `$1`).

Answer (score 0):

There are more than two numbers in each line of data. Your `\d+` will match the first digits from the date at the start of the line.

So you want something that matches your number more specifically. We can make use of the fact that your number all have decimal points. So your match should look like `\d+\.\d+`.

Putting it all together, your code could look something like:

```
my $total = 0;
my $domain = 'www.example.com';

while (<>) {
  next unless /\Q$domain/;
  $total += 1 if /(\d+\.\d+)/;
}

say "Total for $domain is $total";
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl one-liner solution

```
> cat sum_num.txt
26/06/2018 12890765 www.example.com 986.00
31/08/2018 17464946 www.other.com 7627.00
1/05/2018  65472345 www.example.com 14.00
> perl -ne ' { s/(.+)\s+(.+)$/\2/osmg;$x+=$_;print} END { print "Sum=$x\n"} ' sum_num.txt
986.00
7627.00
14.00
Sum=8627
>
```

If you want only the Sum, remove the first print statement